# Should my A/C compressor come on when I turn only the fan on?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, thermostat, nest

I have a bog standard HVAC system with a Nest thermostat. When I tell the theromostat to turn the fan on for 15 minutes the A/C compressor also kicks on. Is this normal?

Comment: Nest, air conditioner running while calling for heat, was burnt back panel. https://community.nest.com/message/27590

Answer (score 1):

This is not normal.  When the thermostat energizes the `G` terminal, only the blower fan should come on.

Check for a jumper/short between `Y` and `G` either at the thermostat, or the air handler.